# Pair two factors for ANOVA in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, anova

I have some colony counts data from two different conditions (cancer and normal) treated with a combination of two drugs: A (3 levels) and B (2 levels). For the colonies I have different types+total but I am OK looking at the different types in a different test.

```
df <- data.frame( Patient = rep( 1:6, 6), Disease = rep( c( "cancer", "normal"), 18), DrugA = c( rep( 0, 12), rep( 30, 12), rep( 100, 12)), DrugB = rep( c( rep( 0, 6), rep( 2, 6)), 3), n.colonies = sample( 10:300, size = 36) )
head(df)
```

My problem is that I want to compare the differences of each treatment (combination of DrugA and DrugB) between the two conditions (cancer and normal). For doing that I have done the following:

```
df$treatment.factor <- paste( df$DrugA, df$DrugB, sep = ".")
library(stats)
a <- aov( formula = n.colonies ~ Disease:treatment.factor, data = df)
summary(a)
TukeyHSD(a)
```

The result returns all possible combinations, including different treatment options within the same condition. I there any way to restrict the tested groups to only the same treatment.factor on different Disease? I was thinking in doing just the t-tests of interest and correct for multiple comparisons but it does not seem completely right for me. I was also thinking in doing a regression for each of the conditions (separated based on DrugB) but having only 3 points (the three concentrations of DrugA) does not help with that either.

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Eduardo

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is an error in your code, here  `df$treatment.factor <- paste( DrugA, DrugB, sep = ".")`, did you mean `df$treatment.factor <- paste( df$DrugA, df$DrugB, sep = ".")`? Also, `TuckeyHSD` is not a base function, from which package does it arrive? Lastly, this seems a question for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) because it's not a only code related question.

Comment: @s_t The base function is `TukeyHSD`. This is a typo.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistakes in the code. I have edited it and it should be clearer. For TuckeyHSD I meant TukeyHSD. 
I will post this in Cross Validated if you think that it is more relevant there. Should I delete the post here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand. Maybe you want:

```
library(lsmeans)
lsmeans(a, pairwise ~ Disease:treatment.factor | treatment.factor)
```

---

```
$contrasts
treatment.factor = 0.0:
 contrast           estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 cancer - normal -101.333333 74.31826 24  -1.364  0.1854

treatment.factor = 0.2:
 contrast           estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 cancer - normal  -92.333333 74.31826 24  -1.242  0.2261

treatment.factor = 100.0:
 contrast           estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 cancer - normal   50.666667 74.31826 24   0.682  0.5019

treatment.factor = 100.2:
 contrast           estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 cancer - normal    1.666667 74.31826 24   0.022  0.9823

treatment.factor = 30.0:
 contrast           estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 cancer - normal    9.000000 74.31826 24   0.121  0.9046

treatment.factor = 30.2:
 contrast           estimate       SE df t.ratio p.value
 cancer - normal   79.333333 74.31826 24   1.067  0.2964
```

Comment: It seems to be doing what I want (basically performing only the contrasts I am interested on). However I need to do a bit of reading as the degrees of freedom are higher than what I would have imagined for a pairwise comparison (5 in this situation?). Also, I imagine that having DrugA and DrugB in the same factor (for making the coding easier) but do you know if it would have an effect in the model? Thanks!

Comment: The only commonality between pairwise comparisons and paired t tests is the sequence of letters p-a-I-r. The *model* is what determines the degrees of freedom, and this one has 24 df for error.